# sending doc attachment mail then it not open correctly

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5

if we are creating the doc extension file by taking the innerhtml of web view then we send it to by mail then it provide the html tag on the quick office2 can anybody help me to solve that problem

this is my code:----

-(void)sendMail
{
    MFMailComposeViewController *mailController = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    [mailController setSubject:@"Sending File From Mobile Office Pro"];
    mailController.mailComposeDelegate = self;

```
NSMutableString *strDirectory = [NSMutableString string];
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
[strDirectory setString:documentsDirectory];


if ([[[Manager sharedManager] arrGlobal] count]>0) 
{
    [strDirectory appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@",[[[[Manager sharedManager]arrGlobal]objectAtIndex:[[[Manager sharedManager]arrGlobal] count]-1]valueForKey:@"DirPath"]]];

}

 NSArray *arrFilesToMove = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:arrForMoveItems];
 NSString *pathToCopyFrom = strDirectory;




NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",pathToCopyFrom,[arrFilesToMove objectAtIndex:0]]];

NSString *mimeType ;

if ([[[arrForMoveItems objectAtIndex:0] pathExtension] isEqualToString:@"csv"])
{
    mimeType = @"application/xlsx";
}
else if([[[arrForMoveItems objectAtIndex:0] pathExtension] isEqualToString:@"doc"])  
{
    mimeType = @"application/msword";
}
else if([[[arrForMoveItems objectAtIndex:0] pathExtension] isEqualToString:@"ppt"]) 
{
    mimeType = @"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation";
}
else 
{
    mimeType = @"application/pdf";
}



[mailController addAttachmentData:myData mimeType:mimeType fileName:[arrForMoveItems objectAtIndex:0]];
 NSString *emailBody = @"Please find attachment generated by Mobile Office Pro for iPhone";
[mailController setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];
[self presentModalViewController:mailController animated:YES];
```

}

Comment: Please add your code here along with your question

Comment: are you getting the full string in the HTML string that you are generating?? and are you again changing the document back to .doc format or just sending it as it is??

Comment: hello mrunal please check my code...here is the doc file that is generated by innerhtml from web view..here is problem only in doc file pdf and xml file are sending fine

Comment: hello iphone developer: i m picking the doc file from document folder that has been generated by innerhtml of webview with doc extension so when we send it by attaching in mail then it coming html format and not display the doc in quick office2

Comment: @mrunal,iphone developer is there any solution for that question please help me to solve that problem i am in very frustrate for that:(